# Shooting bullet towards target

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I'm using unity and trying to get my bullet to shoot at a target. I am clicking the mouse and I'm wanting to fire my bullet in that direction.

I have gotten the coordinates of the mouse click and tried to compute the vector. Then I've tried instantiate the bullet prefab (which has rigidbody component and is in front of the scene) at my position and then fire it in the direction of the mouse.

I can see that my objects being instantiated in my Hierarchy Pane but can't see anything on the screen!

Not sure if I'm doing the vector thing right (newb here), but if I click on Yoshi's head, I'm getting `(-2.0, -0.4)`. Does this sound right?

Code:

```
void fireBullet(float mousePositionX, float mousePositionY)
    {

        Vector2 position = new Vector2(mousePositionX, mousePositionY);
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(position);
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        bullet.transform.LookAt(position);
        Debug.Log(position);
        bullet.rigidbody2D.AddForce(bullet.transform.forward * 1000);
    }
```

[image]

EDIT:

```
void fireBullet(float mousePositionX, float mousePositionY)
    {


        Vector2 position = new Vector2(mousePositionX, mousePositionY);

        //screen space to world space
        position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(position.x, position.y, -1));

        Vector2 direction = (Input.mousePosition - transform.position).normalized;

        //instantiate bullet
        GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        //rotates the transform so forward vector points at targets current position
        bullet.transform.LookAt(position);
        Debug.Log(position);

        //fire the bullet
        bullet.rigidbody2D.AddForce(direction * 1000);
    }
```

Comment: why do you want to shoot yoshi? o.O shoot that asshole mario who consistently pushes him into an abyss just to save his own life!

Comment: What is the resulting position? And what is the position you want? One thing I see right away is that you aren't setting the full position--when you use `ScreenToWorldPoint`, you need to give a x, y, and z position--the x and y are the input, and z describes how far from the camera's plane you want your output to be. So if you need your object to be in the right plane, you need to set that third value.

The most important thing is that you need to know approximately where your bullet *should* be, and you need to know where your bullet is actually being positioned. Tell us and we can help you.

Comment: Okay so I can manually set the third value in `ScreenToWorldPoint` by giving it something the camera can see? My camera's at `-10` so I can place it at `-8` and it should see.

My mouse position on Yoshi's head is `(353, 145)`. Does this sound right?

Comment: the 'z' value should be set based on the order of rendering you need. if your background is at `0`, make the bullet's `z` value `-1`. Ideally, Yoshi and bullet should be on the same z-plane, i.e. `-1`.

Comment: I've added a new bit of code. I've set my screenToWorldPoint and given it three arguments, one being `-1` which is where my scene objects (Yoshi) are being rendered.

Comment: Did you check my answer regarding your bullet sprite's forward vector? I replicated your scenario and that seems like the probably cause.

Answer (score 0):

If your camera is facing the Z direction, your bullet is being spawned with the wrong Z-coordinate. As I mentioned in a comment, you should change your code to tell Unity which z-position to put your bullet in (since for each screen position, there are infinitely many corresponding world positions, most outside the camera's view planes). This is the third value that you need to pass to `ScreenToWorldPoint`, otherwise the offset will be zero and the object will be spawned on top of the camera:

```
float zPos = something; // Wherever your other scene objects are, more or less
float camZPos = Camera.main.transform.position.z;
float zOffset = zPos - camZPos;
Vector3 bulletPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
    new Vector3(mousePositionX, mousePositionY, zOffset));
```

Comment: What do you mean `zPos = something`. What Z position would I be giving this? I have the coordinates of both my mousepositionX and Y but they're both floats and I can't pass a Vector2 to it.

Comment: That is where you want the bullet to go. You need to choose the Z position, since there are infinitely many points corresponding with the screen position of `(0.2, 0.4)`. Unity can't just pick one at random. Oh, BTW I just noticed that your values are negative--those are not good values. The Unity documentation says "Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in world units from the camera." So your x,y values would actually be `-x*Screen.Width, -y.Screen.Height`.

Comment: What x and y values are you talking about? Is this the mouse position? Using the above code and zPos as `-9` it's not instantiating the object where I can see it. But it's not moving towards the mouse click. It looks like the alien is pooing it out.

Comment: @magna_nz The parameters you need to pass to that function are not in the right range. When you are using `ScreenToWorldPoint`, you need to give a x, y, and z value. The x value should be between `0` and `Screen.Width`. So for an x position that's half way across the screen, the coordinate would be `0.5f * Screen.Width`. Do you see why `-0.2` and `-0.4` are nonsense values for this situation? They need to be converted to the proper range. It looks like the current range you have is `(0, -1]`, so you need to multiply as I described.

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure how you mean.

Comment: @magna_nz Okay, `x=-0.2, y=-0.4` is not a point on your screen. That is a point below and to the left of your screen. You cannot use `(-0.2, -0.4)` as a screen point because it is not a valid screen position, like when someone asks you how many beers you want and you say "-3". `(0,0)` is the lower left point. `(Screen.width/2, Screen.Height/2)` is the center. `(Screen.width, Screen.height)` is the upper right. You need to convert your coordinates into this new range. This answer may help: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/32555/

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your scenario and found a possible issue there. Is your bulletPrefab setup such that the forward vector of the prefab is on the same plane as your sprite? Verify this by placing your bullet prefab in scene view. If not, you'll have to set this up.

If your bullet's forward vector is perpendicular to the sprite plane like in the following example, the sprite will not be visible when you are firing the bullet towards Yoshi.

[image]

Solve this by parenting the sprite inside another `GameObject`, and make this GameObject your `bulletPrefab`. Something like this :

[image]
[image]